# How to enumerate enum members using SWIG

Tags: c++, python, swig

Can I expose a C++ `enum` to SWIG as a real entity rather than a set of constants so I can enumerate over them in python code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced the same issue.  I hope that SWIG soon supports C++11's `enum class`.

Here's a hack that convinces SWIG to put enums in a structure:

```
#ifdef SWIG
%rename(MyEnum) MyEnumNS;
#endif

struct MyEnumNS
{
    enum Value { Value1, Value2, Value3 };
};
typedef MyEnumNS::Value MyEnum;
```

In `.cpp` code you now must use `MyEnum::Value1` and in Python code it is `MyEnum.Value1`.    Although convoluted, the `typedef` prevents having to change existing code that uses the enum everywhere and the SWIG %rename makes the enum have the same name in the SWIG wrapper.

In Python you can enumerate the values with a little code:

```
def values(enum):
    return [(k,v) for k,v in vars(enum).items() if isinstance(v,int)]
```

It's not pretty, and I'd love to see a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about something like this, but your answer provides some ready to use pattern, thanks. Can you please explain a bit more on mentioned `sizeof` issue? What code could break exactly, because I don't quite get it.

Comment: I'll remove that part.  It was something I was considering when trying to find an implementation, but I just revisited it and wasn't really an issue.

Answer (score 5):

We can make something that lets you enumerate over it in Python, with relatively little intrusion into the C++ headers it wraps. For example if we have a header file:

```
#ifndef PYTHON_ENUM 
#define PYTHON_ENUM(x) enum x
#endif

PYTHON_ENUM(TestName) {
  foo=1,
  bar=2
};

PYTHON_ENUM(SomeOtherName) {
  woof,
  moo
};
```

It expands to be just a regular enum in C++, but is sufficient as a header file to expose the enum members in Python.

Using `%typemap(constcode)` we can inject some extra things into our Python module for the enum, but we need to know the name of the enum to do this; The SWIG typeinfo object for it is just as if it were an `int`. Therefore we use a bit of a hack in our `PYTHON_ENUM` macro to store the name of the enum in a custom typemap.

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%typemap(constcode) int {
  PyObject *val = PyInt_FromLong(($type)($value));
  SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "$1", val);
  const char *name = "$typemap(enum_realname,$1_type)";
  PyObject *e = PyDict_GetItemString(d, name);
  if (!e) PyDict_SetItemString(d, name, e = PyDict_New());
  PyDict_SetItemString(e, "$value", val);
}
#define PYTHON_ENUM(x) \
        %typemap(enum_realname) int "x"; \
        %pythoncode %{ \
        x = _test.x\
        %} \
        enum x

%include "test.h"
```

This creates a PyDict in the intermediate module for every enum that has key/value pairs. There's also some `%pythoncode` glue there to tie the PyDict in the intermediate module into the exposed module. (I'm not sure how to refer to the intermediate module by name in it, other than hardcoded as _test - change as needed).

This is sufficient that I can then use it as:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> print test.SomeOtherName
{'woof': 0, 'moo': 1}
>>> print test.TestName
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
>>>
```

Comment: So it looks like this being difficult is the consequence of SWIG being simple on purpose, seems like they didn't have in mind bringing C/C++ reflection into scripting languages, just interface generation. Looks like I'll have to go with Mark Tolonen's solution simply because few will understand yours, although I'm on the edge of understanding it right now :D Thank you for an example of trying things with typemaps.

Comment: @unkulunkulu - generally SWIG tries to make it easy to do everything you could in C (or C++), but straying beyond that tends to be harder.

Comment: @Flexo Nice solution. I extended it a bit to import a dictionary, which support dot completion on keys and replaced the `x = _test.x` with `x = dotdict(_test.x)` and added an `%pythoncode %{from dicts import dotdict %}` before the `PYTHON_ENUM` macro.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for are... 
**typemaps**: Since type handling is so central to wrapper code generation, SWIG allows it to be completely defined (or redefined) by the user. To do this, a special %typemap directive is used. (SWIG Doc2.0)

For all the info you could ever need about typemaps here is the link to the SWIG documentation about it.
http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn2

Typemaps should allow you to tell SWIG to convert c++ enums to python objects that you want.

Comment: @Flexo, tbh, I didn't know of typemaps, I'm new to SWIG, they just used it on a project in some darker parts of it, it worked and no one cared, but then I decided to extend it a bit.