# SWIG enumeration creation in Python followup

Tags: python, c++, swig, enumeration

Looking into how to nicely wrap enums in Python using swig, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442110/4251332) answer.

I am trying to create enums like that:

```
#ifndef PYTHON_ENUM 
#define PYTHON_ENUM(x) enum x
#endif

PYTHON_ENUM(TestName) {
  foo=1,
  bar=2
};

PYTHON_ENUM(SomeOtherName) {
  woof,
  moo
};
```

I use the .i file like that

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%typemap(constcode) int {
  PyObject *val = PyInt_FromLong(($type)($value));
  SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "$1", val);
  const char *name = "$typemap(enum_realname,$1_type)";
  PyObject *e = PyDict_GetItemString(d, name);
  if (!e) PyDict_SetItemString(d, name, e = PyDict_New());
  PyDict_SetItemString(e, "$value", val);
}
#define PYTHON_ENUM(x) \
        %typemap(enum_realname) int "x"; \
        %pythoncode %{ \
        x = _test.x\
        %} \
        enum x

%include "test.h"
```

The problem is that this throws AttributeError: module '_test' has no attribute 'TestName'
This stems from the fact that the generated test.py defines the TestName dictionary like that:

```
TestName = _test.testEnum       # This should be in the last line

_test.foo_swigconstant(_test)
foo = _test.foo

_test.bar_swigconstant(_test)
bar = _test.bar
```

At the time where `TestName = _test.testEnum` is called, the _test does not have a `testEnum` member and throws the exception. Once either `foo_swigconstant()` or `bar_swigconstant()` is run, the `_test.testEnum` is generated and the `TestName = _test.testEnum` does not fail. Thus this line should go AFTER the enum value registrations. It works if I do it by hand but I must do it each time SWIG runs which somewhat of a trouble. The same goes for the other enumueration as well. Can I change the interface file to accommodate that?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see this error. I compile and linked the example as follows:

```
swig3.0 -c++ -python test.i
g++ -c -fPIC test_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7
g++ -shared -g test_wrap.o -o _test.so
```

It then works exactly as Flexo suggested. Note that the generated test.py and _test.so reside in the same directory. I use Python 2.7.6 and SWIG 3.0.7 under Debian.

I tried the same using VS2013 and SWIG 3.0.8. What happens is that the `typemap(constcode)` generates functions `woof_swigconstant` etc. rather than inserting const code, which simply exposes static dictionaries. Have you tried this using SWIG 3.0.7?

I looked a little more into this. Using SWIG 3.0.8 and VS2013. The generated code for e.g. the foo entry is:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *foo_swigconstant(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *module;
  PyObject *d;
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char*)"O:swigconstant", &module)) return NULL;
  d = PyModule_GetDict(module);
  if (!d) return NULL;
  {
    PyObject *val = PyInt_FromLong((int)(foo));
    SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "foo", val);
    const char *name = "TestName";
    PyObject *e = PyDict_GetItemString(d, name);
    if (!e) PyDict_SetItemString(d, name, e = PyDict_New());
    PyDict_SetItemString(e, "foo", val);
  }
  return SWIG_Py_Void();
}
```

Hence, a function entry is generated. Using SWIG 3.0.7 and Python 2.7.6 on Debian, I get the following

```
  {
    PyObject *val = PyInt_FromLong((int)(foo));
    SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "foo", val);
    const char *name = "TestName";
    PyObject *e = PyDict_GetItemString(d, name);
    if (!e) PyDict_SetItemString(d, name, e = PyDict_New());
    PyDict_SetItemString(e, "foo", val);
  }
```

inserted immediately after `SWIG_InstallConstants(d,swig_const_table);`. I believe something has changed from SWIG 3.0.7 to 3.0.8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am compiling it with VS2012 for what is worth it, but I am not doing anything differently. The thing is that in the generated .py file, the order of the operations leads to an AttributeError. After playing aroung with the code, I found that by switching the order of the operations as I mention above fixes the problem, but it seems quite counter-productive to have to edit the generated py file. I am working with python 3.5 and SWIG 3.0.7 if that matters.

Comment: Okay. I use Python 2.7 and SWIG 3.0.7 and I get `TestName = _test.TestName` before the `foo = _test.foo`. I don't get any `_test.bar_swigconstant(_test)` entries. It works perfectly for me. Strange. Did you remember the c++ option?

Comment: Tried it here at work using VS2013 and SWIG 3.0.8 and it is not working. I will compare the generated c++ and .py files. The error is in the generated c++ code.