# SWIG- Convert C++ enum to Python enum

Tags: python, c++, enums, swig

I am working to get C++ class enum to python enum using swig. I have the following implementation in example.h file.

```
namespace colors{ 
 enum class Color{
    RED = 0,
    BLUE = 1,
    GREEN = 2
 };
}
```

My Swig interface file is

```
    %module api
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

But after using swig tool the interface provides the following usage

```
import pywarp_example as impl 
impl.RED
```

The question arise here is that is it possible to access enum like below thats the way we use in python?

```
impl.Color.RED Or impl.Color.RED.value
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471213/wrapping-c-enum-in-a-python-module-with-swig

Comment: SWIG predates Python `enum`s by quite a bit. The maintainers will have to add support for `enum`s before you can do that. As far as I know that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Thanks i hope this support add soon :)

Comment: I posted another related solution a while back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442110/168175

Comment: Thanks Flexo for another solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike your example SWIG 3.0.12 would wrap your `enum class` example as `Color_RED`, `Color_BLUE`, and `Color_GREEN`.  Here's an example that adds some additional Python code to remap that pattern into `Color.RED`, `Color.BLUE`, and `Color.GREEN`:

`%pythoncode` is added to the Python portion of the SWIG wrapper.  After the Python extension loads this code runs.  It collects and deletes variables starting with ***prefix_***, renames them without ***prefix_***, then creates a class named ***prefix*** with the new variables as class variables.

```
%module test

%inline %{
namespace colors{ 
 enum class Color{
    RED = 0,
    BLUE = 1,
    GREEN = 2
 };
}
%}

%pythoncode %{
from enum import Enum
def redo(prefix):
    tmpD = {k:v for k,v in globals().items() if k.startswith(prefix + '_')}
    for k,v in tmpD.items():
        del globals()[k]
    tmpD = {k[len(prefix)+1:]:v for k,v in tmpD.items()}
    # globals()[prefix] = type(prefix,(),tmpD) # pre-Enum support
    globals()[prefix] = Enum(prefix,tmpD)
redo('Color')
del redo  # cleaning up the namespace
del Enum
%}
```

Example use:

```
>>> import test
>>> dir(test)
['Color', '__builtin__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_newclass', '_object', '_swig_getattr', '_swig_property', '_swig_repr', '_swig_setattr', '_swig_setattr_nondynamic', '_test']
>>> test.Color
<enum 'Color'>
>>> dir(test.Color)
['BLUE', 'GREEN', 'RED', '__class__', '__doc__', '__members__', '__module__']
>>> test.Color.BLUE
<Color.BLUE: 1>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark much appreciated, is there a way to create python enum instead of class.

Comment: I replaced Enum with IntEnum to allow using it as a function argument

Answer (score 0):

C++ Enum can be converted to python Enum using this script.

```
%pythoncode %{
from enum import Enum
def enum(prefix):
    tmpD = {k:v for k,v in globals().items() if k.startswith(prefix + '_')}
    for k,v in tmpD.items():
        del globals()[k]
    tmpD = {k[len(prefix)+1:]:v for k,v in tmpD.items()}
    globals()[prefix] = Enum(prefix,tmpD)
%}
```